# Is there any way to copy diagrams into different projects?

Tags: staruml

Our team has been using starUML and we had to divide our job to draw sequence diagram for different parts. But now, I am having trouble how to merge those diagrams into one project.

I've searched on net and found out only package can be imported and exported.

Is there any way to just copy the sequence diagram and paste it in the original one?

They are sharing the same constants from the start.

Comment: Years later, this seems to be possible now via the Model Explorer. Create a new model, and copy the sub activities into it, this will copy them including the diagrams.  They can then be modified.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can copy-paste elements only one-by-one. But you should work with Model Elements. [Review](http://staruml.sourceforge.net/docs/user-guide%28en%29/ch04.html) please, first method works for me, but the second

> Procedure for Copying and Pasting View Elements in Diagram

unfortunately doesn't.

**ADDED**

Also you can Export - Import entire diagram as `XMI`

Here is [bug-report](https://sourceforge.net/tracker/index.php?func=detail&aid=1960501&group_id=152825&atid=785399).

Answer (score 3):

1. Open your **source** & **destination** projects in an editor such as Visual Studio Code to view them as json formatted text.
2. In our **source** project json text locate the diagram name which should have an array below it called "**ownedElements**" (which contains all the items in the diagram).

   `"name": "My Diagram Name",
            "ownedElements": [
               ...
            ]`
3. Copy the name & array, then paste in the **destination** json, making sure it is inside of the Project Level "ownedElements" array.

NOTE: Items in an "ownedElements" array **MUST** be separated by a comma so dont forget to include these before and after you paste your text if they are needed.

Comment: Wow. Here we are in 2023 and still doing this quirky trick

Answer (score 2):

in the model explorer view, you can copy a model, then open another star uml with your other project and in the model explorer view, you can now paste the model you have copied.

Answer (score 1):

You can export / import fragments, which are items in the model (in file menu, version 2.5)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, We can copy and paste the diagram with the help of save As... option.

Please find steps as below:
1. create any type of diagram in StarUML and save it. example: sequence1.mdj
2. Then select File >> save As... option or also you can use short cut keys ctrl + shift + S and save it with different name. For example : sequence2.mdj 
3. So now you have 2 different-different files (.mdj). you can modify as you want.

Note: If you simply copy and paste the file then it won't copy content in the second file. This, I already tried. It doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

You can do so from the Model Explorer on the right by copying the Model.

Answer (score 0):

Copy whole model and paste it into other model. Then delete unwanted elements.

Answer (score -1):

you can make select all ctrl+a and past it in paint as image file and start working with it